# NSIS ifSilent not set

Tags: nsis

I'm calling my NSIS compiled `setup.exe` file with `/S` option, so that the 'silent' internal variable is set automatically. Here is my `.onInstSuccess` function. I want to skip an `Exec` command if silent. For some reason the exe is always invoked even if I pass in `/S` in my `setup.exe`

Here is my `onInstSuccess` function

```
Function .onInstSuccess
    IfSilent +2 0
    Exec '"$INSTDIR\Tools\CobraConfigure.exe"'
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Basically I don't want to execute the Exec command if I pass /S in my command line. Should I explicitly call 'SetSilent silent' in .onInit function to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me. Are you doing `SetSilent normal` anywhere in your script?